# what is the best way for usb high data transfer?

Tags: usb, transfer

I want to have 30-Mega byte USB data transfer using cypress FX2LP and also plot it's diagram Simultaneously. I find a strategy that covers this 30 Mega byte transfer rate: reading 1 Mega byte data in Reading-thread and then plotting it in the main_thread. But this strategy requires 1-Mega byte Buffer and I haven't such a memory on my board.

Do you have another solution?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check how to create How to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so that you can get a much better response to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any threads for this.

Break down your problem into simpler steps:

1. How do I measure and collect the data I need?
2. How do I plot the data?

For step 1 - you don't need the actual transfer contents, do you? You just need the timings; basically you want to transfer dummy data, put it into `/dev/null` but save a list of pairs `(nbytes_transferred, timestamp)`, which won't eat that much memory. Save it, test/verify, then proceed to implementing step 2.

---

*Edit*

Threads are not absolutely necessary for smooth UI either.
All you have to do is **avoid blocking/synchronous IO**; use asynchronous/nonblocking methods.
In Java, this means something like NIO; in Qt — maybe use `QtConcurrent` and `QFuture`.

Virtually every GUI toolkit works based on an [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) model: there's a *main loop* rolling (typically hidden inside an `application.run()` call) which again and again queries the OS for *events* (such as user keypresses or mouse usage, timer firings, [asynchronous] network or disk IO completing or progressing, etc), then *handles* or *dispatches* those events, eventually calling your `onButton1Click` methods, — and finally sleeps, until there're more events to process.

There's also, typically, a way to hook onto the `onIdle` "event", which happens right before the mainloop would go sleeping for inactivity (to save the CPU power & energy). In Qt, this is either a 0-timeout `QTimer`, or the `QAbstractEventDispatcher::aboutToBlock()` callback. See [this question](/questions/14893059/emit-signal-when-gui-thread-is-idle-in-qt) for what you like more.

If all this sounds too complex, perhaps check out [this library](https://github.com/bimetek/QUSB) some nice company kindly opensourced on GitHub. (I just found it on google moments ago; no affiliation whatsoever). From the source, it looks like they provide a nice [*Qt-onic*](/questions/25011078/what-does-pythonic-mean) APIs for `libusb-1.0` — which you'll most likely use anyway for cross-platform USB access. Oh, and they chose the 0-timeout `QTimer` approach.

Comment: thank you ulidtko, the benefit of threading for me is user interaction. user should can stop transfer and some other interactions. also i have timer for my work. the timer in my present strategy fires every 1/30 sec.